# How can i work with the rating stars and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am implementing the rating stars provided here [Rating Stars](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#)

, and I am creating a table with PHP and dynamically putting the records in such table. So now, there will be a column for that table where I will be showing those stars. I am saving the value as a number from 1 - 5. When i bind them to my html table how can i tell it inside the `<td>` that the value pulled from the db should be the one checked in other words imagine this

pulled value 3 from db (fields is called rate_num) so the td should look like this

```
<td>
  <input name="star9" type="radio" class="star" disabled="disabled"/>
  <input name="star9" type="radio" class="star" disabled="disabled"/>
  <input name="star9" type="radio" class="star" disabled="disabled" checked="checked"/>
  <input name="star9" type="radio" class="star" disabled="disabled"/>
  <input name="star9" type="radio" class="star" disabled="disabled"/> 
</td>
```

now star9 means that this is on the 9th record, and that 9th record rated as a 3 star.

Ok so that is my first issue

the second issue is to save it, when they click on a star I want to get the value that was checked and somehow convert it to a number 1 to 5 so that i can save it.

I have the db set up with bogus data for testing.. (no real ratings have happened yet). But i am not an expert on PHP or how to go about this. I would appreciate your help.

Any questions please do not hesitate...(instead of down voting)

Regards

Comment: Guys you have been great to me with these answers and both deserve to get the answer. You guys tell me who to give it to... I wish I could give it to both

Comment: I'm indifferent, sorry. thanks though! it was my pleasure to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a value="1" thru 5 on each star. Most likely add a javascript(jQuery) listener for a click, and make an ajax call (POST) to a server-side (php) function that recieves the id of the item & the rating value. If your site has users, make sure they can only vote once.

See your fixed HTML markup (thx mmmshuddup):

```
<td>
    <input name="star9" value="1" type="radio" class="star" />
    <input name="star9" value="2" type="radio" class="star" />
    <input name="star9" value="3" type="radio" class="star" />
    <input name="star9" value="4" type="radio" class="star" />
    <input name="star9" value="5" type="radio" class="star" /> 
</td>
```

1. Create the html of stars - above, only use disabled if you do not want anyone to vote.
2. When user clicks on a star, add an event listener
   `$('.star').click( function() { ajax_call(id,rating); });`
3. This ajax_call() POSTS data to a server side file (e.g. ajax.php).. which checks who has rated the item, if the user has not rated, then add.

**Comment 1:** Yes each block of stars (5 ) should have a distinct "name" or "class", stick to name="star1" .. name="star9" for example. When a user clicks, and that function is called as I suggested, determine which item it is, perhaps find the substring location 4 to the end to get the id.

Comment: Great logic, just a few questions.., I am correct on making sure each <td></td> for each record has a distinct star(number) right? or it does not matter? like in this case i would need to create some loop to add star.$counter or something?

Comment: please reword your question about the loop. I didn't understand it

Answer (score 1):

To add to Mike's answer: If possible, it's better to use GET requests whenever possible, that being said your ajax call would look something like this:

```
$('.star').rating({
    callback: function(value, link) {
       var name = $(this).attr('name');
       $.ajax({
            url: "/path/to/ajax.php",
            data: "name=" + name + "&value=" + value,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) {
                try {
                    console.log(response);
                } catch (err) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: excellent, one more question.. I am noob.. so.. on my <input type='submit' value='Submit' name='submit'/> i would do a OnClick or how do you suggest? I guess the question is how fo i fire the function from this button?

Comment: this scripts submits the rating when the user clicks the stars. (the radiobutton has the class star).

Comment: huh? This function will run each time a user clicks on one of the stars. `callback` is their way of allowing you to add _additional_ functionality to their onclick event listener.

Comment: If its not too much to ask.. how about setting the value of the star?, i am pulling a value from the database 1 - 5. I am using PHP to get the value.. from there i can use anything to assign it

Comment: You could use a loop and test the current `$count` against the the current item's score.

Comment: yeah i did it hehe thank you - also read my comment below my question